# How to cut my excel file into chunks by rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code to split my excel file in chunks (39 rows per file). The code below describes slicing the full-length dataframe into as many files as required. However, a chunk of 39 obs is left behind. Could you help me?

`len(df)` is 571, thus expecting 14 full files of 39 rows each, plus an extra file of 25 rows. I get only 14 files.

```
rows_per_file = 39
n_chunks = len(df) // rows_per_file
for i in range(n_chunks):
    start = i*rows_per_file
    stop = (i+1) * rows_per_file
    sub_df = df.iloc[start:stop]
    sub_df['ID'] = range(1,40)
    sub_df.to_excel(f"RESULT\\{i}.xlsx", sheet_name="Hoja1", index=False, header=True)
if stop < len(df):
    sub_df = df.iloc[stop:]
    sub_df['ID'] = range(1, len(sub_df)+1)
    sub_df.to_excel(f"RESULT\\{i}.xlsx", sheet_name="Hoja1",index=False, header=True)
    
path = '\RESULT\\'
ext = '*.xlsx'
files = []

for dirpath,dirnames,filename in os.walk(path):
    files += glob.glob(os.path.join(dirpath,ext))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indexation and slicing are correct. Except that in the catch section, `i` was not incremented. Look at your last sub_df.to_excel command:

```py
if stop < len(df):
    sub_df = df.iloc[stop:]
    sub_df['ID'] = range(1, len(sub_df)+1)
    sub_df.to_excel(f"RESULT\\{i}.xlsx", sheet_name="Hoja1",index=False, header=True)
```

`i` ends at 13, but a RESULT13.xlsx already exists from the loop. Because of this {i}, this remainder-catching section is set to overwrite the last file from the loop. Use `{i+1}` instead and you should get your 15 files.

Comment: @OliverBriceño all right! In that case please remember that no *thanks* on SO are really complete, until you've accepted the answer ;)